# Chrome Message Passing API does not work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I'm trying to create an extension which tells me if a certain script is used on the current website I'm displaying in a tab.

I have a content script to see which scripts are used an to send messages to the my background script, which handles notification if a tab is switched and changes the icon of my extension to see if scripts are used or not.

This is my content script (load.js):

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({script_found: checkScript()});
function checkScript() {
    var script_found = true;
    var length = document.getElementsByTagName("script").length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
        var list = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[i].src;
        var t = list.toString();
        if (t.length > 1) {
            if((t.indexOf("edge") != -1) || (t.indexOf("prototype") != -1)) {
                script_found = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return script_found;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sendResponse) {
    if(request.tabSwitch == true) {
        sendResponse({script_found: checkScript()});
    }
});
```

This is my background service (background.js):

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(tabSwitch);

function tabSwitch() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {tabSwitch: "true"},function(response) {
            refreshIcon(response.script_found);
        });
    });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request) {
    refreshIcon(request.script_found);
  });


function refreshIcon(script_found) {
    if(script_found) {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"good.png"})
    } else if(!script_found) {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"error.png"})
    }
}
```

I really do not know why it is not working on tabSwitch. It works fine when a website is loaded but it won't when I switch between tabs.

I hope you can help!
Thanks in advance!!

EDIT:
This is my manifest (manifest.json):

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Script Hunter",
  "description": "This extension shows if certain scripts are used on this page.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["load.js"],
    "run_at": "document_idle"
  }],

  "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "good.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

Thanks once again!

Comment: Could you please post your `manifest.json`? I guess your content scripts is injected too late (by default `document_idle`), which causes when `chrome.tabs.onActivated` happens, the script is not injected at all.

Comment: One answer for 99% of comm-related questions: debug it. You'll probably be surprised that `"true"` does not equal `true` among other things.

Comment: @HaibaraAi looks like you're right. What should I change?

Comment: Try to change `document_idle` to `document_start`

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, you're right this is embarrassing, sorry!

Comment: @wOxxOm, aha, good catch!

Comment: @HaibaraAi, the problem if I change it to `document_start`, is that my extension won't find any scripts on the site..

Comment: See my answer, the guess is wrong since you don't need to reload the page in fact, so there is no timing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For background.js, you don't need to query active tab, you could just use the callback parameter of `chrome.tabs.onActivated`. (As @wOxxOm has mentioned in the comments, use `tabSwitch: true` here)

   ```
   chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(tabSwitch);

   function tabSwitch(activeInfo) {
       chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeInfo.tabId, {tabSwitch: true},function(response) {
           refreshIcon(response.script_found);
       });
   }
   ```
2. In load.js, the third parameter for the callback of `chrome.runtime.onMessage` is `sendResponse`, however you only specify two parameters.

   ```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
       ...
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I changed everything but it looks like my background.js recognizes tab switches but doesn't send the info to load.js.

Comment: @r0d, Have you reloaded the web page before to ensure the latest load.js is loaded?

Comment: I had to switch the order of my code. I moved all the functions to the bottom and moved listeners and senders to the top. Fully functional now. Thanks for your help!